# Personal command incompatible with beamer class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-calc

On these thread: [Personal command incompatible with tikz calc library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397321/personal-command-incompatible-with-tikz-calc-library)
the personal `\compo` command that allows you to place a figure next to a text has been corrected to work with the `tikz calc` library and it now works wonderfully. (thanks @Hood Chatham )

But when I use it in the `beamer class`, I have this error:

> ! Package tikz Error: + or -
>   expected.

The macro code is:

```
\newlength{\colG}\newlength{\colD}
% Wrapper command just changes catcodes and calls helper
\newcommand\compo{%
    \shorthandoff{!:}% Change the catcodes
    \compohelper % call helper to grab arguments
}
\newcommand{\compohelper}[3][0.5]{% do actual work
    \setlength{\colG}{#1\linewidth}%
    \setlength{\colD}{\linewidth}%
    \addtolength{\colD}{-\colG}%
    \addtolength{\colG}{-10pt}%
    \addtolength{\colD}{-10pt}%
    \par \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\colG}#2\end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill%    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\colD}#3\end{minipage}%
    \par
    \shorthandon{!:}% restore catcodes
}
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newlength{\colG}\newlength{\colD}
% Wrapper command just changes catcodes and calls helper
\newcommand\compo{%
    \shorthandoff{!:}% Change the catcodes
    \compohelper % call helper to grab arguments
}
\newcommand{\compohelper}[3][0.5]{% do actual work
    \setlength{\colG}{#1\linewidth}%
    \setlength{\colD}{\linewidth}%
    \addtolength{\colD}{-\colG}%
    \addtolength{\colG}{-10pt}%
    \addtolength{\colD}{-10pt}%
    \par \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\colG}#2\end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill%    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\colD}#3\end{minipage}%
    \par
    \shorthandon{!:}% restore catcodes
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}


\compo[.5]{
  Un triangle

}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(-1,-1) rectangle (4,4);
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\coordinate  (C) at (3,0);
\coordinate(D) at (2,0);
\draw(B)--(C)--(D)--cycle;
\coordinate (Ap) at ($(C)!.35!-90:(B)$);
\draw (Ap)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What do I need to change for this command to work with both the tikz calc library and the beamer class?

Comment: Untested but as the code changes catcodes try the [fragile] option for your frames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is changing catcodes, this means that from the point of beamer it is a sort of "verbatim" command and you need to use the `[fragile]` option with the frame:

```
 \begin{frame}[fragile]
```