# How can I put text next to an image

Tags: graphics

I have this:

```
\begin{figure}[!hb]
 \label{curve}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=4cm]{images/smoothSinCurve.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{trivlist}  
\item \textcolor{orange}{Orange} is overdose
\item \textcolor{green}{Green} is underdose
\item \textcolor{blue}{Blue} is perfect dosage.
\end{trivlist}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

How can I put them on the same line?

Comment: You can insert the text inside `\caption{}` inside the `figure` environment. Not use items.

Comment: Its still underneath

Comment: can you add an ECM ?

Comment: @vonhact, so you don't want on line below? Edit your post to make it clear.

Comment: @Sigur Its very clear.. `How can I put them on the same line?` Maybe you should read the entire post first. Others below gave excellent answers.

Comment: @vonhact, for sure I read all the post. It is not my fault if you didn't explain well. *same line* could be same line as the figure, or all items in same line, but still below figure. Also, what is *them*? The items? Everything?

Comment: Maybe the word in the title should be *besides* an image...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[!hb]
\centering
 \label{curve}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=4cm]{example-image}
\begin{minipage}[b]{1.4in}
\begin{trivlist}  
\item \textcolor{orange}{Orange} is overdose
\item \textcolor{green}{Green} is underdose
\item \textcolor{blue}{Blue} is perfect dosage.
\end{trivlist}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a command that allows to do this simply. It was corrected by @egreg who wrote it as an environment here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/403618/138900

I have since modified it giving the possibility to put or not a vertical separation line:

```
\newlength\colG\newlength\colD%
\newenvironment{Compo}[1][0.5]
 {%
  \setlength{\colG}{#1\linewidth}%
  \setlength{\colD}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\colD}{-\colG}%
  \addtolength{\colG}{-10pt}%
  \addtolength{\colD}{-10pt}%
  \par\noindent%
  \begin{minipage}{\colG}%
 }%
 {%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par%
 }%
\newcommand{\compobreak}{%
  \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\colD}%
}%
\newcommand{\componubreak}{%
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\colD}%
}%
```

Which gives here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% nouvel environnement Compo
\newlength\colG%\newlength\colD%
\newenvironment{Compo}[1][0.5]
 {%
  \setlength{\colG}{#1\linewidth}%
  \setlength{\colD}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\colD}{-\colG}%
  \addtolength{\colG}{-10pt}%
  \addtolength{\colD}{-10pt}%
  \par\noindent%
  \begin{minipage}{\colG}%
 }%
 {%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par%
 }%
\newcommand{\compobreak}{%
  \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\colD}%
}%
\newcommand{\componubreak}{%
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\colD}%
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}   
\begin{Compo} [.5]
 \label{curve}
    \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=4cm]{example-image}
\compobreak

\begin{trivlist}  
\item \textcolor{orange}{Orange} is overdose
\item \textcolor{green}{Green} is underdose
\item \textcolor{blue}{Blue} is perfect dosage.
\end{trivlist}
\end{Compo}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]