# Is there an easy way to align the baseline of the beginning of two columns?

Tags: multicol, baseline

When I do this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
{\Large Équations}
\columnbreak

{\Large Calculs et raisonnements}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

Is there a way to force the first baselines to be at the same level?

The solution I'm thinking of now is to add a `\vphantom`.

## edit

PS: Here is why I use `\columnbreak`. Without `\columnbreak`, my document doesn't look well balanced.

[image]

## edit 2

Here is another instance of when I need to `columnbreak`...

[image]

Comment: Guessing the intended purpose of your document, it could be convenient to switch to a `longtable` or `longtabu` environment. I can post an example as answer if you want.

Comment: I think this is an XY question: I think, like @MaxSnippe, this should be a table rather than a `multicols` environment.

Comment: No, it is a `multicols` document!

Comment: The use of `multicols` is suspicious because of the `\columnbreak`  multicol is all about automatic column breaking  and balancing, here suspicion is that if you added more equations than fit in a column you would want them to flow in to the left column of the next page, but multicol would put them in the right column of this page.  Of course you can add more code changes to make things appear in the correct column but it is an indication that the wrong tool is being used. You can knock a nail in with a screwdriver, but a hammer may be a better choice.

Comment: Also, using a tabular environment would help keeping the equation on the left properly aligned with its reasoning on the right. That could be a pain when using `multicols`.

Comment: I’m sorry if the titles of the sections made you think that I wanted to organize equations and other things. I use multicols for lists of exercises. In this case, some exercises were Equations and other Computations or more abstract exercises. Anyway. The thing is that for some reasons, I have to in this case to manage manually the change of columns. That’s why I use columnbreak. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: See my edited question.

Comment: I only said it was "suspicious" not necessarily wrong:-) so my answer is the answer in that case:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `\topskip` to be big enough to hold the accented capital

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

{\setlength\topskip{15pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
{\Large Équations

}
\columnbreak

{\Large Calculs et raisonnements

}
\end{multicols}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**A second solution** using the `tcolorbox` package.

The idea is to use the `sidebyside` option of the `tcolorbox` package which displays the upper and lower parts of the boxes side by side.

The space between the two columns is given by the `sidebyside gap` parameter, here 3mm.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% box creating the box "double column"
\newtcolorbox{double column}{notitle,lower separated=false,
enhanced,sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,sidebyside gap=3mm,
sharp corners,boxrule=0pt,colback=white,
}


\begin{double column}
\lipsum[1]

\tcblower

\lipsum[2]

\end{double column}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `Compo` command that allows to show a figure next to a text but that can just as well place two texts or 2 images side by side.

It was corrected by @egreg who made it an environment: [Conflict between personal macro and Babel French](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403589/conflict-between-personal-macro-and-babel-french)

Here an example by default where the minipage is separated into two equal parts as well as two other examples where the minipage is separated into two unequal parts and separated by a vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% nouvel environnement Compo
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403589/conflict-between-personal-macro-and-babel-french

\newlength\colG\newlength\colD%
\newenvironment{Compo}[1][0.5]
 {%
  \setlength{\colG}{#1\linewidth}%
  \setlength{\colD}{\linewidth}%
  \addtolength{\colD}{-\colG}%
  \addtolength{\colG}{-10pt}%
  \addtolength{\colD}{-10pt}%
  \par\noindent%
  \begin{minipage}{\colG}%
 }%
 {%
  \end{minipage}%
  \par%
 }%
\newcommand{\compobreak}{%
  \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\colD}%
}%
\newcommand{\componubreak}{%
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{\colD}%
}%

% fin environnement Compo
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{Compo}% by default .5
{\Large Équations}
\componubreak 
{\Large Calculs et raisonnements}
\end{Compo}

\smallskip

\dotfill
\smallskip

\begin{Compo}[.4]
{\Large Équations}
\compobreak 
{\Large Calculs et raisonnements}
\end{Compo}

\smallskip

\dotfill
\smallskip

\begin{Compo}[.6]
{\Large Équations}
\compobreak 
{\Large Calculs et raisonnements}
\end{Compo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks André but I prefer to use `multicols`. I think it matches more my needs (cf. the edited question)

Comment: To make 2 columns, the environment that I propose answers your two problems since the content of each column is filled manually by yourself and is not automatic. That's why I personally stopped using multicol which is more appropriate for writing newspapers or magazines.